# Java TreeMap comparator not serialized using jackson mapper

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a comparator that parses String (ex: car-00001) and does numeric comparison:

```
public final class IdUtils {
  public enum MyNumericIdComparator implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
INSTANCE;

public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
  Optional<Long> l1 = IdUtils.parseNumericIdOrNull(s1);
  if (l1.isPresent()) {
    Optional<Long> l2 = IdUtils.parseNumericIdOrNull(s2);
    if (l2.isPresent()) {
      return l1.get().compareTo(l2.get());
    }
  }

  return s1.compareTo(s2);
}
```

The TreeMap is created using

```
public class MyOuterObject {
private NavigableMap<String, MyObject> map;
//other fields

@JsonCreator
public ResourceInstanceSetEntity(@JsonProperty("resourceSetId") final String resourceSetId) {
    super();
    this.map = Maps.newTreeMap(IdUtils.MyNumericIdComparator.INSTANCE);
    ...
    }
}
```

But when I serialize it using Jackson Mapper, the output json does not record the comparator information and deserialized map does not have the comparator:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());

MyOuterObject set = new MyOuterObject("some id");
set.putMap(a,b); //add a record to map
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(set);
```

What am i missing?

Edit:
I am trying to avoid deserialization creating a map without comparator and when i need to use it, create another treemap, add comparator and load data to the new map with old map which i feel is unnecessary.

If comparator type cannot be serialized, is there a way to create an empty treemap with my comparator and ask jackson mapper to PUT items into it?

Comment: That's expected behaviour - it outputs maps as json objects with keys and values. If you want something else, you'll need to write a custom serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain more why this is expected? because i have "setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)" i thought it would serialize everything including private field of TreeMap.

Comment: Basically, it is expected because that is what the tutorials say.  For example: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations.  See the example serialization for a map.  Jackson serialization of maps is "built in" to the object mapper.

Comment: @StephenC I don't see map specific section in the link. Which number is it?

Comment: I am talking about the example in 2.1.  See how the map is serialized ... and how there is no mention of the implementation class for the map.